# Why was there such a large gap between the US and UK release of Wreck-It Ralph?

Tags: distribution, wreck-it-ralph

Wreck-It Ralph had it's World Premier October 29th 2012 and was released in the US a few days later on November 2nd 2012. The UK release of the film was a couple of months later on 8th February - was there any reason behind this delay? Films normally come out on the same day, or a couple of days apart rather than months.

The film is available online, to buy for digital download, from Feb 12th and the DVD/Blu-Ray from March 5th - when the film will still be in cinemas. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: I am not sure I would call this a duplicate because it is a specific movie case.Think about it.

Comment: @Mistu4u - I can see your point but I'm not sure I entirely  agree.  "Films normally come out on the same day" .... this is a general statement, and not always true.  Prometheus opened over a period of 2 months for example.

Comment: @iandotkelly, `...or a couple of days apart rather than months. ` The OP mentioned it. So it can be concluded he is not unknown of the fact.Yet he had query about this specific movie. He also had a thought what might be the case: `The film is available online, to buy for digital download, from Feb 12th and the DVD/Blu-Ray from March 5th - when the film will still be in cinemas. Does this have something to do with it?`

Comment: I believe that, jsut because a question that has most of the gnerl answers, doesn't mean it coverts all of the cases which could cause these delays.  I am for reopening this question.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's clear up a misconception. Films *don't* normally "come out on the same day". It is more common for this to happen nowadays, but many films still have several weeks or months between American release and European/worldwide release. (10 years ago, in the UK we had to wait 6 months in most cases.)

There are several reasons why films are released at different times, including cost, negotiating distribution rights and local sensitivities. Some of this is answered here: [Why is international distribution so tangled even for recent movies released first online?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/why-is-international-distribution-so-tangled-even-for-recent-movies-released-fir)

In the specific case of *Wreck-It Ralph*, movies targeted at children are usually released to coincide with school holidays to take advantage of daytime showings. It is currently "half-term week" in the UK (some schools last week, some this week) so it was released last week to maximise attendance.

If *Wreck-It Ralph* was released last November in the US I suppose it could have been released in December to take advantage of the Christmas holidays, however I believe cinema attendances are lower during that period (as people prefer to stay at home or are busy visiting relatives).